# Scala: Why does my Scala Test custom matcher not compile?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scalatest

I'm working exercises from the book [Learning Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449367933) and one question asks:

> Create a container class that has an instance of itself plus an
>   instance of a parameterized type. The constructor should take a
>   variable number of the instances (e.g., strings or ints or any other
>   parameterized type), which can be implemented with vararg parameters.

I came up with the following:

```
sealed abstract class MyList[A]

sealed class MyNil[A] extends MyList[A]

sealed case class Cons[A](h: A, t: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]

object MyNil {
  def apply[A] = new MyNil[A]
}

object MyList {
  def apply[A](items: A*): MyList[A] = {
    items match {
      case h :: t => Cons[A](h, apply(t: _ *))
      case _ => MyNil[A]
    }
  }
}
```

So far, so good. The issue is with testing this code. The following test using Scala Test and a custom matcher does not compile, more specifically the `isEqual` method. Can you help me understand why?

```
class MyListSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "MyList" should "be instantiated as expected" in {
    val inputAndOutput = Table(
      ("ip", "op"),
      (Nil, MyNil[Int]),
      (List(1), Cons[Int](1, MyNil[Int])),
      (List(1, 2), Cons[Int](1, Cons[Int](2, MyNil[Int]))),
      (List(1, 2, 3), Cons[Int](1, Cons[Int](2, Cons[Int](3, MyNil[Int]))))
    )

    forAll(inputAndOutput) { (ip, op) =>
      val o = MyList(ip: _ *)
      println(o)

      o should equal(op)
    }
  }

  def equal[Int](right: MyList[Int]) = new MyListMatcher(right)
}

class MyListMatcher[Int, A <: MyList[Int]](val right: A) extends Matcher[A] {
  override def apply(left: A): MatchResult = {
    MatchResult(
      isEqual(left),
      s"""MyList $left did not match "$right"""",
      s"""MyList $left matched "$right""""
    )
  }

  def isEqual[A <: MyList[Int]](left: A) = {
    left match {
      case _: MyNil[Int] if right.isInstanceOf[MyNil[Int]] => println("Both are Nil."); true
      case Cons[Int](h, t) if right.isInstanceOf[Cons[Int]] => {
        println("Both are Cons.")
        left == right
      }
      case _ => println("No match."); false
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit 1**:
Included all compile error messages from IntelliJ on request:

```
Error:(31, 40) inferred type arguments [Nothing,name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[Int]] do not conform to class MyListMatcher's type parameter bounds [Int,A <: name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[Int]]
  def equal[Int](right: MyList[Int]) = new MyListMatcher(right)
                                       ^
Error:(31, 58) type mismatch;
 found   : name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[Int]
 required: A
  def equal[Int](right: MyList[Int]) = new MyListMatcher(right)
                                                         ^
Error:(27, 9) overloaded method value should with alternatives:
  (endWithWord: org.scalatest.words.EndWithWord)(implicit ev: <:<[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int],String])MyListSpec.this.ResultOfEndWithWordForString <and>
  (startWithWord: org.scalatest.words.StartWithWord)(implicit ev: <:<[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int],String])MyListSpec.this.ResultOfStartWithWordForString <and>
  (includeWord: org.scalatest.words.IncludeWord)(implicit ev: <:<[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int],String])MyListSpec.this.ResultOfIncludeWordForString <and>
  (notExist: org.scalatest.words.ResultOfNotExist)(implicit existence: org.scalatest.enablers.Existence[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]])Unit <and>
  (existWord: org.scalatest.words.ExistWord)(implicit existence: org.scalatest.enablers.Existence[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]])Unit <and>
  (containWord: org.scalatest.words.ContainWord)org.scalatest.words.ResultOfContainWord[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]] <and>
  (haveWord: org.scalatest.words.HaveWord)MyListSpec.this.ResultOfHaveWordForExtent[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]] <and>
  (beWord: org.scalatest.words.BeWord)MyListSpec.this.ResultOfBeWordForAny[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]] <and>
  (inv: org.scalactic.TripleEqualsSupport.TripleEqualsInvocationOnSpread[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]])(implicit ev: Numeric[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]])Unit <and>
  [U](inv: org.scalactic.TripleEqualsSupport.TripleEqualsInvocation[U])(implicit constraint: org.scalactic.Constraint[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int],U])Unit <and>
  (notWord: org.scalatest.words.NotWord)org.scalatest.words.ResultOfNotWordForAny[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]] <and>
  [TYPECLASS1[_], TYPECLASS2[_]](rightMatcherFactory2: org.scalatest.matchers.MatcherFactory2[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int],TYPECLASS1,TYPECLASS2])(implicit typeClass1: TYPECLASS1[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]], implicit typeClass2: TYPECLASS2[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]])Unit <and>
  [TYPECLASS1[_]](rightMatcherFactory1: org.scalatest.matchers.MatcherFactory1[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int],TYPECLASS1])(implicit typeClass1: TYPECLASS1[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]])Unit <and>
  (rightMatcherX1: org.scalatest.matchers.Matcher[name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyList[scala.Int]])Unit
 cannot be applied to (name.abhijitsarkar.scala.MyListMatcher[Int(in class MyListMatcher),A])
      o should equal(op)
        ^
Error:(46, 21) name.abhijitsarkar.scala.Cons[Int] does not take parameters
      case Cons[Int](h, t) if right.isInstanceOf[Cons[Int]] => {
                ^
```

Comment: "Does not compile" should never be included in a question without the error message.

Comment: @user2864740 I sorta agree with you but there are multiple compile error messages and I thought it'd be confusing to dump all here.

Comment: Then start by finding out which one(s) are applicable. Most are secondary fall-out of a previously non-compiling code/types and can probably be eliminated the excluding non-relevant code.

Comment: @user2864740 I added the compile errors in an edit. I find your suggestion another way of saying "fix it yourself", which I'll keep on trying to do. If you've something more specific from the code above, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, the following test code works. The catch was to not include the `Int` type parameter with the `Cons` case in method `isEqual`.

```
class MyListSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "MyList" should "be instantiated as expected" in {
    val inputAndOutput = Table(
      ("ip", "op"),
      (Nil, MyNil[Int]),
      (List(1), Cons[Int](1, MyNil[Int])),
      (List(1, 2), Cons[Int](1, Cons[Int](2, MyNil[Int]))),
      (List(1, 2, 3), Cons[Int](1, Cons[Int](2, Cons[Int](3, MyNil[Int]))))
    )

    forAll(inputAndOutput) { (ip, op) =>
      val o = MyList(ip: _ *)
      println(o)

      o should equal(op)
    }
  }

  def equal(right: MyList[Int]) = new MyListMatcher(right)
}

class MyListMatcher(val right: MyList[Int]) extends Matcher[MyList[Int]] {
  override def apply(left: MyList[Int]): MatchResult = {
    MatchResult(
      isEqual(left, right),
      s"""MyList $left did not match "$right"""",
      s"""MyList $left matched "$right""""
    )
  }

  def isEqual(left: MyList[Int], right: MyList[Int]): Boolean = {
    left match {
      case _: MyNil[Int] if right.isInstanceOf[MyNil[Int]] => println("Both are Nil."); true
      case Cons(h, t) if right.isInstanceOf[Cons[Int]] => {
        println("Both are Cons.")
        val r = right.asInstanceOf[Cons[Int]]

        h == r.h && isEqual(t, r.t)
      }
      case _ => println("No match."); false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is this line here:

```
def equal[Int](right: MyList[Int]) = new MyListMatcher(right)
```

**TL;DR**

Change this:

```
class MyListMatcher[Int, A <: MyList[Int]](val right: A) extends Matcher[A] {
```

To this:

```
class MyListMatcher[A <: MyList[Int]](val right: A) extends Matcher[A] {
```

**Full Explanation**

The issue you're having is simply that the Scala compiler trying to figure out what type argument your new `MyListMatcher` instance should be.

Because your `MyListMatcher` class is a type constructor which takes two arguments (one is hardcoded to be an Int and the other is inferred from the constructor argument), the Scala Compiler sees this and assumes that the first parameter is an Nothing because it is not specified in the `equal` method.

Simply remove the first Int type parameter and your issue will go away

Comment: You're probably right (I didn't verify) but I didn't need the type parameters, see my own answer.

Comment: I already checked you can either use `MyListMatcher[Int, Cons[Int]]` or remove the Int type paramater. You can close the question now though with either of the two answers :)

Comment: I went with my own answer that I posted little before your's. Who doesn't like their own code? I, however, upvoted your answer for taking the time.